# gatsby-plugin-image Load image with the given prop

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

Consider I have the following component

```
// variant can be one of [facebook, google, apple, ...etc]
<CompanyLogo variant="facebook"/>
```

The number of possible values of `variant` is finite.

I would like to dynamically load the corresponding image depending on the value of the `variant` prop.

Now, I have thought of 2 ways to do it.

**Option 1**: Query all company logo images using GraphQL and find the one I need using JS.

```
const { images: { edges: images } } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      images: allFile(filter: {
        sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}, 
        relativeDirectory: {eq: "companies"}
      }) {
        edges {
          node {
            name
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

const image = images.find(({ node: { name } }) => variant === name );
```

*The concern I have is that I'm not sure whether this will greatly impact performance*, especially when there are many company logos.

**Option 2**: Use `switch` or `if` condition to load the images

```
switch (variant) {
  case 'facebook':
    return <StaticImage src="facebook.png" />
  case 'apple':
    return <StaticImage src="apple.png" />
  // ...etc
}
```

*The issue is the code is really smelly.*

Do you have a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the two approaches, option 1 is the best approach for you.

Keep in mind that in a switch/case approach you will be evaluating all cases until your option is matched, like if you had a bunch of `if`s. Option 2 is the lowest performance approach.

I would add a third trial, which in my opinion is the most performant, a dictionary (map):

```
const LOGO_VARIANTS = {
 facebook: <StaticImage src="facebook.png" />,
 apple: <StaticImage src="apple.png" />,
 potatoes: <StaticImage src="potatoes.png" />,
 'dashed-logo':  <StaticImage src="dashed-logo.png" />
}
```

Then, you only need to access the position with the key-value like:

```
const SomeComponent = () =>{

   return <div>My logo is {LOGO_VARIANTS['facebook']}</div>
}
```

*Note: tweak that logic to adapt it to your needs, like assigning the `LOGO_VARIANTS['facebook']` to a new variable and render it like: `const Image= LOGO_VARIANTS['facebook']` and then `<Image/>`*

I'm not sure about the whole logic and this approach may not be the best/optimal solution for you. If you don't want to overkill the logic, I would use the option 1 which is far better than the 2.

Comment: Will querying all images at once hurt the performance and memory usage? I'm not sure how Gatsby handles GraphQL queries, do they perform it on runtime or build time?

Comment: In the build-time. https://www.gatsbyjs.cn/docs/use-static-query/

Comment: Ah, then the performance impact is not that great after all.

Comment: Nope, at this point, it's not a matter of performance (even a switch/case with 3 options has a meaningless impact rather than the other options) but readability. For a small project, you won't notice any difference between any approaches. But in large projects, the build process may delay because of this kind of technical decissions